# undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass error but no nil exists?

Tags: ruby

Was wondering why I get the error: "undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass" when compiling.  After looking for reasons why, I found that you cannot use [] on an object with nil as a value.  This makes sense, but I don't see why my array would contain nil in it.  What am I missing?

```
   def binary_search(n, arr)
  middle = arr.length #pick middle value
  i = 0
  j = arr.length - 1

  while i <= j
    if arr[middle] == n
      return true
    elsif arr[middle] < n
      i = middle + 1
      middle = (i + j) / 2
    else
      j = middle - 1
      middle = (i + j) / 2
    end
  end
  false
end

nums = [76,32,50,90,10,8,15,49]
nums.sort
puts nums.inspect
binary_search(50, nums)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a simplified subset of the code:

```rb
arr = [76,32,50,90,10,8,15,49]
middle = arr.length # 8
arr[middle] < 50 # NoMethodError
```

- The `length` is 8.
- `arr[8]` is `nil`, because there is no item at index 8. Remember that Ruby indexes begin with 0.
- `nil < 50` is a `NoMethodError`